# Can I run both Windows and Linux Dwarf Fortress from the same directory?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

The reason I'm asking this is because I want to play Dwarf Fortress mainly on my main Windows computer, but I'd also like to be able to continue the same save from my Linux VPS.

I already know how to synchronise the folder, but I'm just wondering if I might run into any trouble by running both Windows and Linux executables from the same source.

Comment: Both exexutables in the same time ?

Comment: No, just in the same folder, so I can synchronise that folder among the two systems.

Comment: @Arda A very good question which unfortunately I cannot answer...

Comment: If both have access to the same save files then you will be fine as long as you're not running two copies of Dwarf Fortress at the same time. But what do you mean by running from the same source?

Comment: From the same folder, pretty much.

Comment: I will run a diff on the different versions to see what the differences are.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes**. As far as I can see, and have tested, there should be no problem running both versions from the same (merged) folder. Here is the output of

```
diff -ur ./df_linux ./df_windows
```

> ```
> Only in ./df_windows: compress_bitmaps.bat
> Only in ./df_linux/data/art: Thumbs.db
> Only in ./df_linux: df
> Only in ./df_windows: Dwarf Fortress.exe
> Only in ./df_windows: fmod.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: fmodex.dll
> Only in ./df_linux: g_src
> Only in ./df_windows: jpeg.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: libpng12-0.dll
> Only in ./df_linux: libs
> Only in ./df_windows: libtiff-3.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST
> Only in ./df_windows: Microsoft.VC90.CRT.MANIFEST
> Only in ./df_windows: msvcm80.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: msvcm90.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: msvcp80.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: msvcp90.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: msvcr80.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: msvcr90.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: msvcrt.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: optipng.exe
> Only in ./df_windows: optipng license.txt
> Only in ./df_linux/raw/graphics/example: Thumbs.db
> Only in ./df_linux: README.linux
> Only in ./df_windows: SDL.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: SDL_image.dll
> Only in ./df_windows: zlib1.dll
> ```

**all other files are identical**

*(Toady left some `Thumbs.db` from Windows in the linux version, bad Toady!)*

As you can see, the only noticable differences are the libs for the Linux version and DLL files for the Windows version, and that each version has it's own executable, which is key for mutual co-existence (*;)*)

You can even use a modded Windows version of DF and add the required Linux files to it to be able to play it on Linux.